# ¿Cómo acceder a localhost desde cualquier equipo de una red doméstica?

Tags: aplicación-web, servidor, redes, wamp

He desarrollado un pequeño sistema bajo jquery, para lo cual utilicé wampserver como servidor web para la fase de desarrollo, lo cual anduvo bastante bien.  Ahora, necesito instalar este sistema en un entorno de 5 computadores, de modo de dejar uno de ellos como servidor web, donde esté wampserver y desde los restantes equipos puedan acceder enviando requerimientos de páginas del sistema, es decir, que desde estos equipos puedan acceder al localhost y levantar sesiones en el sistema.

He revisado información que circula en la web y hablan de modificar el httpd.conf, lo cual he hecho, pero no logro levantar sesion en el sistema desde las otras computadoras.

Alguien me puede ayudar indicándome cómo se puede realizar lo anterior.

Mi wampserver v2.2 tiene Apache v2.4.2

---

Aporto más antecedentes:

- La empresa que me brinda internet, puso un modem desde donde sale toda la conectividad; a este modem no se puede acceder para confguración.
- Los equipos se conectan por wifi.
- Las ip son dinámicas. Por ejemplo, en el equipo en donde tengo el wampserver, la ip es 192.168.1.21. En otro equipo (cliente), desde el cual trato de acceder al servidor web, la ip es 192.168.1.22
- Si desde este último equipo  cliente, hago ping a 192.168.1.21, me arroja:
  Haciendo ping a 192.168.1.21 con 32 byte de datos:

Respuesta desde 192.168.1.22: Host de destino inaccesible.

Respuesta desde 192.168.1.22: Host de destino inaccesible.

Respuesta desde 192.168.1.22: Host de destino inaccesible.

Respuesta desde 192.168.1.22: Host de destino inaccesible.

Estadísticas de ping para 192.168.1.21:
Paquetes: enviados = 4, recibidos = 4, perdidos = 0 (0% perdidos)

El equipo donde esta wampserver tiene windows 8.1 y el equipo cliente tiene windows 8.1

Comment: Entiendo que todas y cada una de las máquinas quieren acceder usando "localhost" a sí mismas y que no estamos hablando de red entre ellas en ningún momento, ¿no?. Bien, eso ya es así por defecto siempre si usas localhost, prueba a hacer ping en cada máquina a este nombre y verás que te resuelve siempre la ip de loopback 127.0.0.1 que es siempre la ip de "uno mismo". A partir de ahí, ya tienes nombre de dominio sobre el que configurar tu Apache "localhost" que te va a funcionar para todas las máquinas igual, accediendo a si mismas.

Comment: La verdad es que lo he vuelto a leer y no queda nada claro lo que quieres... no se si es lo que te comentaba en mi comentario anterior... o si es que solo tienes un servidor y quieres acceder a él desde otras máquinas de tu red local. Bueno, si es esto lo que quieres (que no lo sé), pues para acceder a este server tendrás que tener red funcionando entre ellas y poner la ip (o nombre, pero esto ya sería más complicado teniendo server DNS o jugando con los hosts), así que de momento con ip... desde las otras máquinas puedes acceder a ese servicio en `http://laIpEnRedLocalDeTuServer`

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. Sí, talvez hice confusa la pregunta cuando puse "que desde estos equipos puedan acceder al localhost y levantar sesiones en el sistema.".  Lo que necesito es poder dejar un equipo como servidor web y desde los otros equipos poder acceder al sistema que está  publicado en dicho servidor.

Comment: Bueno, pues lo primero es verificar que están en red y que tienes conectividad entre ellos. ¿Qué sistemas operativos son? ¿haces ping entre ellos? ¿qué rango de ips tiene tu red y cual es la del server?

Comment: Puse más antecedentes en el cuerpo de la pregunta principal.

Comment: [`ngrok`](https://ngrok.com/) es una herramienta muy completa y simple de usar, que sirve para exponer un servidor local detrás de un NAT o firewall a Internet.

Comment: Veo que no haces ping entre las máquinas aunque están en el mismo rango ip. Puede ser por dos cosas... una, porque tengas el ping capado en el windows, o dos, porque tengas en el punto de acceso el "Client isolation" que aisla a los clientes unos de otros. Si es esto último lo vas a tener muy complicado si quieres que vean el servidor web las otras máquinas de la red, ya que indicas que no tienes forma de entrar a la configuración del router/AP.

Comment: Gracias @Marcos Gallardo por tu sugerencia. Voy a revisar de qué se trata, cómo se usa y cómo me puede ayudar en lo que requiero.

Answer (score 5):

Esto es para crear un "virtual host"

**Empecemos**

**Paso 1:** Lo primero que debemos hacer es crear el directorio donde alojaremos nuestros virtual hosts, por ejemplo en la carpeta principal crearemos un directorio llamado proyectos:

**C:\virtualhost**

Dentro de esta carpeta es donde guardaremos nuestros proyectos. Para este tutorial vamos a suponer que tenemos un nuevo proyecto en Laravel de manera que la carpeta de acceso pública a dicho proyecto esté en esta ruta: **C:\virtualhost\sitiolocal\public**.

Puedes usar cualquier directorio o crear cualquier proyecto, sólo recuerda la ruta.

**Paso 2**: Lo siguiente que debemos  hacer es dirigirnos a **C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc** y modificar el archivo **hosts**, pero para modificar el archivo necesitamos permisos de administrador por lo que primero abrimos el Bloc de Notas como administrador y abrimos la siguiente dirección **C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts**.

Nos aparecerá de esta manera el archivo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este archivo agregamos nuestro host virtual, para agregarlo lo hacemos de la siguiente manera:

`IP               Nombre de Host`

Entonces nosotros agregaremos nuestros host apuntado a 127.0.0.1 que es la dirección IPv4 de la maquina local, y después el nombre de nuestro hosts. Podemos agregar los host que deseemos pero siempre apuntando a **127.0.0.1**

`127.0.0.1        misitio.local`

**Paso 3:** Ahora debemos modificar el archivo de configuración de Apache, para incluir el archivo de configuración de virtual host, lo podemos abrir de igual manera con un bloc de notas.

Si están en XAMPP, la ruta será la siguiente: **C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf**

Si están en WAMP, la ruta será la siguiente: **C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\conf\httpd.conf**

Lo siguiente es buscar las siguientes dos líneas que están resaltadas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eliminen el **#** de la segunda línea.

Además dentro del mismo archivo debemos asegurarnos de que el módulo Rewrite está habilitado, para ello buscamos la siguiente línea:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Y nos aseguramos de que no esté comentada (el signo de numeral # sirve para comentar líneas), si no tiene el signo quiere decir que ya está habilitada.

Realizado esto guardamos los cambios.

**Paso 4**: Lo siguiente es abrir el archivo de configuración que nos provee **XAMPP** o **WAMP**, de igual manera lo podemos editar con un Bloc de Notas.

Si están en XAMPP, la ruta será la siguiente: **C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**

Si están en WAMP, la ruta será la siguiente: **C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**

El archivo lucirá de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es en este archivo donde alojaremos cada uno de los host virtuales que creemos, lo haremos de la siguiente manera:

Primero agregamos la directiva Directory, es aquí donde activaremos el uso de URL’s amigables, necesarias para el funcionamiento del framework PHP que utilicemos (ejemplo: el poderoso **Laravel**), lo agregamos antes de la configuración de NameVirtualHost, y es aquí donde debemos recordar el nombre que le establecimos a nuestra carpeta, además de todo usaremos la diagonal convencional y no la invertida para descripción de direcciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo siguiente es agregar nuestro virtual host, y lo agregamos de último a nuestro archivo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recuerda reemplazar c:\virtualhost\sitiolocal\public con tu directorio en caso de que sea diferente.

Cuando se habilita el uso de Virtual host, Apache desactiva la carpeta raíz del servidor, por lo que antes de todos los virtual hosts debemos agregar la carpeta que nos provee XAMPP o WAMP para alojar nuestras paginas. En este caso yo utilice XAMPP:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota:** si te ha tocado cambiar el puerto donde escucha Apache que por defecto es 80 a otro puerto (ejemplo: 8080), en ese caso ese el número de puerto que debes de poner en el encabezado de Virtual Host ejemplo:

Realizado todo esto procedemos a  guardar nuestro archivo, y ahora nos toca reiniciar Apache, y probar el acceso al host virtual en el explorador en el caso de este ejemplo la dirección sería:

`htttp://misitio.local/`

Si estás construyendo el sitio en Laravel y ves lo siguiente es porque has seguido los pasos de forma correcta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo lo hago tal cual y me funciona correctamente.

[Fuente](https://styde.net/creando-virtual-hosts-con-apache-en-windows-para-wamp-o-xampp/)

Éxitos y saludos.

Answer (score 0):

te cuenta tenes que modificar
el archivo httpd-xampp (en wamp no se cual sea pero debe ser muy parecido)

en las ultimas lineas 
dice algo como

## New XAMPP security concept

#

bueno ahi pones

```
   Allow from all
```

quedaria asi

#

## New XAMPP security concept

#

## Close XAMPP security section here

Order deny,allow

```
Allow from all  # ahi seria permiteme las peticiones de todos los ip
```

## en ese comando tambien te sirve para acceder del exterior si tu router esta configurado con los puertos 80.

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
```

espero que te sirva posiblemente esa igual o muy parecido el archivo httpd-xampp

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que revisar por que generalmente los modem domésticos tiene una opción en su administración que aisla los clientes de la red, es decir todos los cliente podrán estar en el mismo rango de red pero no se podrán ver.

Si les haces ping los paquetes se pierden ademas como estas en windows abre una carpeta y ahora en la partes izquierda dale donde dice **red** luego hay te tiene que aparecer algun equipo de esa forma saber si los equipos que estan conectado a la red se pueden ver entre si.